# Currencies and prices configuration in Google Pay

Tags: google-pay

does anybody knows why prices aren't shown in Google Pay popup for some countries. It's always showed for Europe, but isn't showed for Canada, US, Australia etc. Do I missing something in configurations of Google Pay.

I was looking congigs in Google API don't see anything specific to countroes or region

Answer (score 0):

`totalPrice` is only getting displayed on the Google Pay sheet for EEA countries. This is due to [SCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_customer_authentication) requirements.

[image: totalPrice developer docs]

https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/reference/request-objects#TransactionInfo